# Ruby: Delete all non-string elements from an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to write a function in ruby that, given an array with different datatypes, returns a new array of only the string elements. For example, given the array:

```
arr = [1, 3, 'hello', 'goodbye', 20, 'arrays are fun']
```

I would like to write a function that returns a new array that looks like this:

```
new_arr = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'arrays are fun']
```

Is there a built in function in ruby that accomplishes the separation of datatypes in a given array? I was able to accomplish it with the below loop.

```
result = arr.select do |elem|
   elem.is_a? Integer
end
```

But I was wondering if Ruby had a built in function to achieve what the loop is doing, something like, say, `arr.integers` that takes an array and only returns integers.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
array.delete_if { |obj| !(obj.is_a? String) }
```

Comment: Or `keep_if` to avoid the `!`

Comment: thanks! I also found `.grep` to work!

Answer (score 0):

I found a method `grep` which worked!

```
def remove_non_strings(array)
  array.grep(String)
end
```

Comment: `grep` returns a new array, it doesn't modify the existing one.

Comment: I didn't know that. They both worked for my program but that is a good distinction to know. Thank you!